# gsutil cp pipe fails in docker container as a bash exec command

Tags: bash, docker, google-cloud-platform, cp, gsutil

I'm trying to run a bash script in the cloud-sdk Linux container as part of an ETL pipeline, basically trying to use `gsutil` and `sed` to solve a problem with the way Cloud SQL exports MySql csv data (nulls are written as a weird, unclosed quote artifact, `"N`, which needs to be removed before the data can move onward or be parsed. It's been an open issue for the Cloud SQL team for > 2 years).

The command is

```
gsutil cp gs://bucket/dir/file.csv - | sed 's/"N,/,/g' | gsutil cp - gs://bucket/dir/file.csv
```

And the error:
`CommandException: cp: "gs://bucket/dir/file.csv" and "gs://bucket/dir/file.csv" are the same file - abort.`

I've tried also splitting up the pipe into two steps:

```
gsutil cp gs://bucket/dir/file.csv - | sed 's/"N,/,/g' > file.csv &&
gsutil cp file.csv gs://bucket/dir
```

but that fails too, with the same error, which makes no sense to me. The first one runs in the CLI to completion, though the file that makes it to GCS has 0 bytes. The second one works without trouble in the CLI, but not when called as a bash command executed by a Docker container.

All I can imagine is that the two commands are being run at the same time, and so are attempting to simultaneously access the same resource, but that shouldn't be the case with the ordering of the operations -- unless exec for container doesn't wait for operations to complete?

Edit: well, the cp - is a streaming process, so I guess it makes sense that that would continuously pipe input into sed, and sed has to write somewhere, so sed would have to stream the input straight back to gcs, though changing the output file name isn't solving the error. And 2 should be working, unless the second command after && executes while cp - continues streaming (changing the output file name here also doesn't solve the issue).

Answer (score 1):

You could try making a copy of your file to another bucket:

gsutil cp gs://[SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME]/[SOURCE_OBJECT_NAME] gs://[DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME]/[NAME_OF_COPY]

Then make the changes in the file (in the 2nd bucket):

sed 's/"N,/,/g' gs://bucket/dir/file.csv

Then simply delete the old file and move the new file, in the 1st bucket:

gsutil mv gs://[SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME]/[SOURCE_OBJECT_NAME] gs://[DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME]/[DESTINATION_OBJECT_NAME]

Its a longer process, but something you can keep inmind.

For your reference: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects

Comment: But that doesn't identify the cause of these errors, why these particular solutions aren't working. There are plenty of workarounds, including just throwing away the entire approach.